# Cross platform Pipenv.lock

Tags: python, cross-platform, pipenv

I have a "cross-platform" `Pipfile.lock` file in my repo, i.e. have entries such as:

```
"ptyprocess": {
    "hashes": [
        "sha256:923f299cc5ad920c68f2bc0bc98b75b9f838b93b599941a6b63ddbc2476394c0",
        "sha256:d7cc528d76e76342423ca640335bd3633420dc1366f258cb31d05e865ef5ca1f"
    ],
    "markers": "os_name != 'nt'",
    "version": "==0.6.0"
},
```

This works great with `pipenv sync` - i.e. when run on windows it does not install `ptyprocess` and when run on linux it does. However, if I `pipenv install` a new package on windows, it will **remove** the above entry from `Pipfile.lock` when locking. If the lock file is then checked in to source control (as is generally recommended) and a linux user runs `pipenv sync` then the required package will no longer be present.

Is this is the desired behavior from `pipenv`? If so why? What would be the right way to manage the cross-platform case above?

Comment: Maybe PEEP-005 will help if it is implemented?
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/peeps/PEEP-005.md